# Update page parameter responses without overwriting DTMF settings

Tags: node.js, typescript, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to update responses of page parameters using the SDK, but I'm running into an issue where the DTMF settings that I've set via the web UI are being disabled when I update the responses via the sdk.

I've tried adding a first level updatemask like so:

```
await this.pageClient.updatePage({
  page,
  languageCode,
  updateMask: {
    paths: ['form']
  }
```

This sadly still overwrites the DTMF settings of each parameter on the page. I've tried looking into ways to create an update mask for nested properties, but I found no examples in the docs on how I could do this. I've only gotten invalid mask errors back from Dialogflow in my attempts.

I know that DTMF settings [are unavailable](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#form) in the SDK, so it could be that what I'm trying to do isn't possible, but would it be possible to use an update mask that only overwrites the responses in a parameters as a workaround, something along the lines of `form.parameters.fillbehavior.initialPromptFulfillment.messages`?

Comment: Can you share the error message you are facing from the dialogflow cx?<br>

Comment: It was just a generic `Invalid mask` response. I got it each time I tried to add an update mask for properties of `form`, like so: `form.parameters`.

Comment: Hi @Jordi, As you mentioned in the question DTMF feature is [unavailable](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#form), So If you want this feature in DialogFlow cx, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).